# How to input relation into two dimensional array?

Tags: java

I have a problem in my project math.

My project is to write a program that reads a set of elements and its relations. Your input data will be from a text file. (SetRelation).

`{1,2,3} {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)}`

I have no problem reading the text file into the program but I'm stuck when I want to try to put the relation into the two dimensional array.

For example: `{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)}`

The two dimensional array would have to be like this:

```
col[0][1][2]
[0] 1  1  1
[1]    1  1
[2]       1
```

I don't know how to set one into two dimensional array because there are various relations in the text file.

This is my coding.

```
import javax.swing.*;
       import java.util.ArrayList;
       import java.io.*;
       import java.util.StringTokenizer;
       import java.lang.*;
       import java.util.*;

       public class tests 
       {
          public static int s1[][];
          public static int s2[][];
          public static int s3[][];
          public static int s4[][];
          public static int s5[][];
          public static int s6[][];
          public static int s7[][];
          public static int s8[][];
          public static int s9[][];
          public static int s10[][];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        BufferedReader infile = null; 

        ArrayList arr1 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList arr2 = new ArrayList(); 
        ArrayList arr3 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList arr4 = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
              infile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("numbers.txt"));

              String indata = null;

              while ((indata = infile.readLine())!= null) 
              {
                     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(indata," ");
                     String set = st.nextToken();
                     arr1.add(set);
                     String relation = st.nextToken();
                     arr2.add(relation);
              } 

              for(int i =0; i < arr2.size(); i++)
              {
                  String r = arr2.get(i).toString();
                  String result = r.replaceAll("[{}(),; ]", "");
                  arr3.add(result);
              }

              for(int i = 0; i < arr3.size(); i++)
              {
                  System.out.println(arr3.get(i).toString());
              }

              for(int i =0; i < arr1.size(); i++)
              {
                  String s = arr1.get(i).toString();
                  String result = s.replaceAll("[{}(),; ]", "");
                  arr4.add(result);  
              }

              int set1 = Integer.parseInt(arr4.get(0).toString());
              String ss1 = arr4.get(0).toString();
              int a = ss1.length();
              s1 = new int[a][a];
              int sA[][];
              /*for(int row=1;row< a;row++)
              {
                  for(int col=0;col < a;col++)
                  {
                      sA = new int[row][col];
                      int firstNo = Integer.parseInt(arr3.get(row).toString());
                      int secondNo = Integer.parseInt(arr3.get(col).toString());
                      sA = new int [firstNo][ secondNo] ;  

                      System.out.print(sA);
                  }
                  System.out.println();
              }*/
              char arrA;
              char indOdd=' ',indEven=' ';
                 char[] cArr = arr3.get(0).toString().toCharArray();
                 //System.out.println(arr3.get(0).toString().length());
                 int l = arr3.get(0).toString().length();
                 int arr10[][] = new int[(l/2)][2];

                    for(int i=0;i< 2;i++)
                    {
                        for(int row = 0; row < (l/2);row++)
                        {
                            for(int gh = 0;gh < l;gh++)
                            {
                                if(i%2==0)
                                {
                                indEven = cArr[gh];
                                System.out.println(indEven);
                                arr10[row][i] = indEven;
                                //System.out.println(arr10[row][i]);
                                //row++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                indOdd = cArr[gh+1];
                                System.out.println(indOdd);
                                arr10[row][i] = indOdd;
                                //row++;
                            }
                         }
                        }
                            //arr10 = new int[indOdd][indEven];
                            //System.out.println(arr10);
                    }         

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {
               System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
               System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        infile.close();


    }
}
```

But I'm stuck how to set one into the two dimensional array if the relation is `{(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,c),(c,c)};` and `{(33,33),(45,45),(67,67),(77,77),(78,78)};`

Answer (score 1):

So, you have two problems: parsing the input and setting the array.

To parse the input, think about the format you're given. An opening curly brace, a bunch of ordered pairs, then a closing brace. Think about this pseudocode:

```
Read in a left curly brace
While the next character is not a right curly brace{
    Read in a left parenthesis
    Get the first number and put it in a variable!
    Read in a comma
    Get the second number and put it in a variable!
    Read in a right parenthesis
    Store your relation in the array!
}
```

Now your issue is just how to put it in the array. Your relations are practically already indexes into the grid! Note the 0-indexing, so just subtract 1 from both, and set the resulting coordinate equal to 1.

```
array[first number-1][second number-1]=1;
```

Comment: Well, it's pretty hard to read your code in a comment; you could edit your question, and after pasting it in, select it, and click the curly braces so that it's formatted as code. But, looking at it there, it looks like you're tokenizing by spaces? Your example input didn't have spaces. If the format is what you showed in the question, you're going to want to read it in one character at a time, not a line at a time. No idea what a and b are in your code snippet there.

Comment: For having characters instead of numbers: the lazy, ugly way is to index based on the characters (a char is actually a number). The nicer (slightly longer) way is to store the input as chars, then you have a bunch of if statements for turning the chars into coordinates. Aka, if it's an a, put it in spot 0, if it's a b, put it in spot 1, etc...

Comment: sorry,this is my first time.  the input was in a text file. that's why i separate set and relation. set in a array, relation another array.

Comment: Well, step back and think about what your code is doing. First, you're splitting the input based on spaces, but you have no spaces. Then you're adding strings to arrays when you need to be indexing in and setting values. Trying logically planning out what you're going to do (my pseudocode should give some structure). Also, if you want to keep the set, don't add every single character, only add characters that aren't already there.

Comment: You have a 2D array arr? Just say arr[row coordinate][column coordinate]=1 to set it to 1. We've already discussed how to get the coordinates, so hopefully that's clear.

Comment: Errm, the code that didn't make sense before hasn't changed. Have you tried the things we've been suggesting? If you're having trouble seeing why your code doesn't work, put comments in to show your line of thought, and I'll explain where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Just a TIP:

If your set is for example `{b,c,e}` and want to have somewhere stored relation `elemnt <-> index` like `b<==>0`, `c<==>1`, `e<==>2` you can store that elements in `List` and then use method `indexOf()`.

I mean something like this

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("e");
System.out.println(list.indexOf("c"));//return 1
System.out.println(list.indexOf("e"));//return 2
System.out.println(list.indexOf("b"));//return 0
```

Now you just have to figure out how to use it to create your array.

Comment: nice idea, but if the input definately consists of single characters, I would rather use List<Character>.

Comment: @user1461081 another Tip: if your data in String are in this form `{a,b,c} {(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(a,b),(a,c),(b,c)}` then `split` (there is such method in String object) it in place where space is. This way you will separate set elements from relations set.